# Xbox Button keeps coming back after being unpinned from taskbar

Tags: taskbar, microsoft, xbox360

Alright I was trying to remove the Xbox button from the taskbar. I found the following information. Can anyone confirm that this works? I have tried this but it came back anyway... what step am I missing?

Open Windows Explorer (files, MyComputer, whatever) and type this in the address bar: %LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\

Right click on LayoutModification.xml and select "OPEN WITH > NOTEPAD > JUST ONCE"

Search (scroll to the bottom or CTRL+F) for "xbox"

Remove the whole line(s) containing the word Xbox.

Save the file.

Unpin Xbox from the taskbar.

Restart computer.

Comment: does it work for you?

Comment: We kind of expect that if you've found a solution, you try it.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not a question.

Comment: I did try this but the icon came back anyway, so what am I missing here?

Comment: I still have NO IDEA why MS is pushing the "Xbox" button to hang out on a taskbar on new computers. This was very difficult to remove and it shouldn't be that way.

Answer (score 0):

Alright I found my error, I apparently did not save the XML back to the same location and overwrite the original... I saved it as a .txt in my documents folder, which was obviously wrong. So, following the steps as written works, with the addition of ensuring the original XML is overwritten!

I was also able to remove some other persistent buttons by removing those lines from the XML file as well. After a restart, the buttons are remaining OFF my taskbar.